# C# DllImport - number of parameters doesn't match

Tags: c#, dllimport

I try to reverse a C# assembly with .NET Reflector. I'm interessted in the external function `func` which is declared like this:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public class Class
{
...
[DllImport("extern.dll")]
public static extern uint func(IntPtr a, ulong b, int c, int d, int e);
...
}
```

So I opened `extern.dll`with IDA and searched for the function `func`. The decompilation looks like this:

```
int __fastcall func(__int64 a1, __int64 a2, unsigned int a3) {...}
```

In the C# Code the function is invoked with 5 parameters:

```
uint ret = Class.func(this.a, b, this.c, this.d, e);
```

In the C# assembly there are 5 parameters and in the external dll are only 3 parameters. So my question is how can this work?
I have absolutely no idea how the 5 parameters are mapped to only 3.

I hope someone can help me so i can continue reversing the external dll.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Markus

Comment: @user469104 because this shouldn't work **at all** and there's not enough information to figure out what's really going on, but there's a pretty good chance he's just looking at the wrong function or something like that. (I'm not either of the downvoters)

Comment: @RobertRouhani i agree that this shouldn't work. Thats the reason i asked how this is possible. If i look at the wrong function, how can i determine which function is the correct one? I'm very new to IDA.

Comment: This makes no sense. Wrong number of args. Wrong calling convention. Perhaps it's the wrong dll. Or IDA is wrong. Or the wrong function. Unless you are an expert at asm, reversing is going to be beyond you. So either give up, or get stuck into asm.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The dll is x64. And as i know there is only the fastcall calling convention in x64. Also it's the only dll with that name and there is only one exported function with the name `func`inside that dll. So i assume i'm looking in the correct dll and the correct function. Maybe i just have to adjust some options in IDA but i don't know which one. Giving up isn't an option.

Comment: So, dig into the asm. One wonders why you feel the need to reverse anything though. I mean, the interface of the DLL is clearly stated by the C# p/invoke. Why do you need IDA at all?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because i want to know what's going on inside that function

Comment: So use a debugger. Step into the function, and see what the address is. Check that it matches what IDA says is the address of the function. Check that matches the address in the PE export table. A decompiler can only guess as to how many parameters there are with a register calling convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i looked into the assembly of `func` and noticed that only 3 parameters are used by the function. Thats the reason why IDA recognized only 3 params.

To verify this i wrote a little function with 5 params which uses only the first 3 params. Then i call that function with 5 params. I decompiled it and the result was the same: IDA only recognized 3 params.